# jquery not working when elements added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that jquery just works with elements on `DOM`, but I don't know how to solve my problem though I searched a lot.

This is my code:

```
<script>
    var actions = {{json_encode($actions) }};
    var options = "";
    for(var key in actions){
        if(key == ""){
            options = ('<option value>'+actions[""]+"</option>") + options ;
        }else{
            options = options+ ('<option value="'+key+'">'+actions[key]+"</option>");
        }
    }
    var select = '<select name="action_id[]">' + options + "</select>";
    var label = '<label>Action</label>';
    var span = '<span>{{$errors->first('action_id')}}</span>';
    var a = '<a  class="removeAction2" href="javascript:"></a>';
    var li = '<li>' + label+ select + span+ a +'</li>';

</script>
```

I used that code when I click on a link like:

```
 this$(".addAction2").on('click', function(){
        console.log(li);
        $(li).insertBefore(".lastLI");
    });
```

The `a` has a class `removeAction2`.

This is the function for it:

```
$(".addAction2").on('click', function(){
        console.log(li);
        $(li).insertBefore(".lastLI");
    });
```

**This function is in `document.ready`**

That function doesn't work. In other words, when I click on `a`, nothing happens.

Though if I added the `a` tag in `html` (not dynamically) it works.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', ".addAction2", function(){
        console.log(li);
        $(li).insertBefore(".lastLI");
    });
```

You need to delegate the event. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ as above I have delegated to the `document`

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$(document).on("click", ".addAction2", function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: +1 but there is a guy answered first, I wish I could accept more than one answer

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too. seems like he did while I was still writing it LOLz... Anyways it's nice of you to consider upvoting Thanks.